# SSRS - Indicator and value in same cell?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have created a Directional indicator (Green up arrow and Red down arrow) in my SSRS report, referring to the value of the column next to it.  This all works ok:

[image]

However, I really want the indicator and the value to be in the same cell, like Excel can:

[image]

A Google found the [following article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f5f19834-ba37-410c-bb7e-179807dfefea/indicator-value-in-same-cell?forum=sqlreportingservices) , where the last post suggest it is possible using the following syntax:

```
=Format(Fields!Column1.Value, "Format") + " " + "Indicator"
```

I assume "Indicator" refers to the name I gave to my Direction indicator, but I can't get it to work..

[image]
[image]

I have read that by using border formatting I can get my two cells to look like one, but I would ideally like it all to be in one.

Any thoughts appreciated!

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by placing a Rectangle inside of the cell and place your indicator along with another text box inside the rectangle. The downside to this is (depending on how you align the items in the rectangle) the formatting may cause split cells in excel exports.

Answer (score 0):

Ross's method will work and there are alternatives..

The article you referenced was a text indicator not an image (from what I could tell). 
You could do something similar by simply adding a a placeholder in the cell (right-click inside the cell and click "create placeholder"). You can then set the font and colour independently from the rest of the cell. 
You could use a common font such as wingdings to get arrows and then the value and color properties would be expressions to show the correct 'character' (arrow) and the correct colour.